# Error when sum up sales in a single month and modify the month to every first day of that month

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to analyse the sales on each month, and trying to sum up the sales for each month and display the date as 1st day of that month. However, I get this error when converting my Order Date to every 1st day of that month, the order date become:

```
"2018.0 - 9.0 - 01"
```

My code is

```
df_sales['Order Date'] = df_sales['Order Date'].dt.year.astype('str') + '-' + df_sales['Order Date'].dt.month.astype('str') + '-01'
df_sales['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sales['Order Date'])
```

and when I do error checking:

```
import pandas as pd 
import io
print(df_sales[df_sales['Order Date'].str.len() > 7])
```

I have the outcome as above

```
Order Date

2018.0-09.0-01

2018.0-03.0-01

2017.0-04.0-01

my original data is this:

2018-09-21

2018-09-03

2018-03-05
```

something like this.

and I wish my data to become something like this:

```
Order Date  Sales

2018-09-01  5466

2017-03-01 6466
```

which is order date is to be every 1st day of the month, and sales would be the total sales of that particular month.

how should I modify my code to achieve the result?

Much thanks!

Comment: Please include all data in your question as text, not as images.

Comment: @DYZ oh ok im sorry will modify it

Comment: Can you also include your original dataframes output?

Comment: @RSM Hi my original dataframe is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df_sales['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sales['Order Date'])
df_sales['Order Date'] = df_sales['Order Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks all of you for giving me ideas and inspirations, I finally found out that the error is my dataset, there are quite a few of empty fields which I didn't clean properly. My code works.